# Issue while creating an android project with phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

When I try to create native android project in eclipse it works perfectly fine, and that shows my android setup is proper but when I try to create a phonegap project it create a error ie:

```
./create ~/Documents/workspace/HelloWorld com.fizzysoftware.HelloWorld HelloWorld

BUILD FAILED
/Users/mohit/Documents/eclipse/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:710: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/mohit/Documents/eclipse/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:723: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 5 seconds
An unexpected error occurred: ant jar > /dev/null exited with 1
Deleting project...
```

cordova version: 2.7
Android api version 14

*Ps: I am a ruby on rails developer. This is my day 1 with phonegap/android/ios*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest as a bare minimum first step you should check via the command line that the following commands return a response that shows they are working correctly. They are all required.
Ant - http://ant.apache.org/

Java -http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-jdk-7u1-downloads-523391.html

android - http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

In command line type the following to validate they work

Ant

java

android

Also make sure you look at you PATH file and that everything is correct there.

As I say that's the basics (once you have stuff installed)

Answer (score 0):

I thinks there are issues with setup only. There are lots of stuff to do before setting the phonegap app for eclipse or any other IDE.I don't know from which site you have build the or set the IDE for the phonegap application development framework. Here is the link i am providing build your project step by step through this guide. I am sure there will be no issues.I have developed the application and tested it. that's why i am sharing with you.Here is the Link:
[Getting Started with Phonegap in Eclipse](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html)